# Parsing using decodable when value of a dictionary is an array of strings

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decodable

I want to parse the json file below, but I keep getting the following error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

I have looked on stackoverflow, but they didn't seem to help as I don't see other json files that returns a dictionary value that is an array of strings. Any ideas?

```
//JSON file
{
 pugs: [
   "http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lqfwfyZuyS1qiyqyfo1_500.jpg",
   "http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_liic7bdmRF1qcipjro1_500.jpg",
   "http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ll3xdp73DQ1qb08qmo1_500.jpg",
   "http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lht5uy6khS1qed3e3o1_500.jpg",
   "http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lrqnevtBvM1qb08qmo1_400.jpg",
   "http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ll90kwmMJw1qzj3syo1_500.jpg",
   "http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ll7aoxHGfW1qb08qmo1_500.jpg",
   "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lk27smb4sR1qzj3syo1_500.jpg",
   "http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lil8a1m1YM1qzj3syo1_500.jpg",
   "http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_liy1xfY9G71qftdfxo1_500.jpg"
  ]
}
```

```
//Data Model
class PugList: Codable {
    var pugs: [Pug]
    var likes: Int
}

class Pug: Codable {
    var images: [String]
}
```

Comment: Btw, json which you've showed isn't valid... you're probably missing `]`

Comment: @RobertDresler thanks for catching that. I didn't post the entire array and was missing the closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Pug` class. Change `pugs` to `[String]`.

BTW - use `struct` instead of `class` unless you have a good reason to use a class.

Comment: ... or even to `[URL]` 

Comment: @mir Glad to help. Please don't forget to indicate that your question has been resolved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.